# Exporting Binary items from Broker database - Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013, broker

I have some issues with the original implementation of Binary file storage being placed in the Broker database.  In a recent deployment we decided to utilize File system storage in favour of performance impacts on the Broker database itself.

This has worked well for that particular project, however is there a way we can now change how other projects work in retrieving all of the Binary items from the Broker database, placing them on the File system and serving that way?

Would like to perform this WITHOUT having to republish entire sites, due to the sheer amount of content that would not be practical.

Thanks

Martin

Answer (score 4):

Given that it's not just a question of moving the files (their metadata must be adjusted too) I would really prefer to do it via republishing. I know you say it's unpractical/time consuming, but it is the *safest* way to do it.

If this is really not an option, then I would:

- Compare thoroughly the differences (in metadata) between a binary in the File System vs a Binary in the Database (with a bit of luck, there's no difference)
- Write some code using the CD API to retrieve the binaries and store them in the right location in the File System (making sure it matches the metadata)
- Change cd_storage_conf.xml to reflect the new location of the binaries

This should do it.

One of the biggest advantages of storing Binaries in the database is distribution of the same binaries. If you have a multiple server farm, not having to deploy to multiple file systems can be a significant advantage, and when coupled with caching I have not see performance issues with this approach before. What is arguably the [largest SDL Tridion](http://www.hp.com) deployment in terms of page views uses this model.